# How to extract square root sign from a bitmap image?

Tags: image-processing

I have a bitmap image, from which I want to know if the square root sign is present or not and what is its position.[image]

Comment: Are the symbols always the same size and shape? May they appear with different "font type"? Have you tried something so far? Which programming language are you expecting to use?

Comment: Size will vary but font type will not. Currently I am using typescript.

Comment: Have you tried something in particular? Will the images be as clean as your example?